# Second order non linear equation $y''=p(x)y'+q(x)y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to resolve the following differential equation :
$$y'=k1A0+(k2A0e^{-\alpha x}-k1)y-k2e^{-\alpha x}y^2$$

I used substitutions described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation.
So, I wonder if it exists an analytical solution to this second order non linear equation :

$$u''+(k1+\alpha-k2A0e^{-\alpha x})u'-k1k2A0e^{-\alpha x}u=0$$

After some attempts, as $x+z=A0$, I found  a more simple differential equation :
$$z'=-(k2A0e^{-\alpha x}+k1)y+k2e^{-\alpha x}y^2$$
So,
$$u''+(k1+\alpha+k2A0e^{-\alpha x})u'=0$$
But, I still could not find the solution.
Indeed, I am not able to integrate :
$$u'=Ke^{\frac{k2A0}{\alpha}e^{-\alpha x}-(k1+\alpha)x}$$

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes, there is one which is a monster ! What about the boundary conditions ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. Thanks for the answer. The boudary conditions are : y(0)=0 and y($\infty$)=A0. I hope it will simplfy the monster !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. I edited my question. Perhaps, it could help. In this case, z(0)=A0 and z($\infty$)=0

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. In this problem, k2A0>>k1 and k2A0>>$\alpha$

Comment: The discussion Carl Bender goes through on this matter is worth a watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tV-xIhP7VU8

Comment: Also, check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation